# создание ссылок из веб формы

Tags: парсер, веб-скрейпинг

минимально знаком с pyton прошу помощи в направлении поиска решения.
имеется сайт на котором генерятся реламные ссылки
имеется файл эксель с входными данными (id товара)
на выходе нужно получить сгенерированную ссылку и записать ее в эксель
какие есть варианты решения? нужно сгенерить порядка 4500 ссылок за раз
вот сама веб форма
[image: скрин с формы вебсайта]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: всегда надо начинать с того, что изучить код сайта, а именно как генерятся ссылки, для этого на данном этапе пайтон не нужен

Comment: ... пайтон не нужен, а нужно нажать F12 в браузере и посмотреть код, который запускается при нажатии кнопки "сгенерировать ссылку"

Comment: @S.H. сможешь помочь?

Comment: ну, я как мог - помог, целый ответ написал :-) Если вопрос срочный - то второй метод из моего ответа вполне может сработать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть 2 подхода: программистов и "эфективных менеджеров" (то есть "чего думать, трясти надо!").

Если Вы хотите воспользоваться первым подходом, то правильным советом будет изучить код сайта, потом понять, по какому API он работает, и написать свою реализацию клиентской части: чтобы эта реализация брала данные из Excel, направляла их в API и результат - сгенерированную ссылку - добавляла в excel.

Второй подход - *может* быть основан на любой программе, котрая умеет записывать дейтвия пользователя (нажатия на клавиатуре, клики мышкой и т.п.- AutoIt, например). Вы можете "накликать" действия, котрые приводят к генерации одной ссылки - ну, там, встать на следующую строку excel, скопировать в буфер, переключиться в браузер, нажать tab столько то раз, чтобы курсор встал в поле, куда нужно вставть id товара, потом еще столько то раз, чтобы стала активной кнопка "сгенерировать", нажать enter, перейтив поле со ссылкой, выделить всё, записать в буфер, переключиться в Excel, вставить из буфера... И потом выполнить записанный сценарий в цикле. Преимущества - никакого программирования, хотя сама по себе работа довольно непритязательна...

Comment: я склоняюсь ко второму варианту, так как решение разовое и для новичка более реализуемо, чем API интеграция. но при генерации 4500 ссылок это займет порядка недели непрерывной работы. насколько быстро может генерировать ссылки бот написанный на pytone с библиотекой silenium

Comment: практически, скорость бота, написанного на селениум огранничена скоростью ответов сайта, который генерирует ссылки. К тому же, можно запустить несколько ботов в виртуалках. Если сайт Вас не забанит - наверное, получится 2-3 секунды на ссылку, можно за полдня успеть.